# Sphere Point Picking

Tags: random-generation

As explained [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html), sphere point picking can be performed using the easy formula

$x$ =  $\sqrt{1-v^2}\cos\theta$

$y$ =  $\sqrt{1-v^2}\sin\theta$

$z$ =  $ v$

where $\theta\in [0, 2\pi]$ and $v \in [-1,1]$

Does anybody know, who first presented this method? I would like to see a rigid mathematical proof for that and cite it, and not the mentioned website. I think the underlying method is related to generating random numbers on a cylinder and then projecting it to the sphere as discussed [here](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1188&context=cis_reports). However, i could not find a rigid mathematical proof for that.

Comment: This result is a standard exercise in multivariate Calculus, so you should be able to find a proof in any textbook that has a solution manual.  I believe it has been known since the Classical Greek period.

Comment: I checked several books and almost all articles in the first 5 pages of scholar.google.com. I have found different methods for generating random points on sphere. But not with these formulations. For example [here](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1188&context=cis_reports) it seems it discussed the same method of wolfram page, but without the formulation written in the website.  Interesting that there is reference for all methods of this website, except the first one, that i am interested in.